# Issue with scrapy python from two class spiders

Tags: python, scrapy

I have two spiders class called 'categories' and 'articles', where the  categories class contain all the url  what i need pass to the articles class. But i don't know how do it.

Can somebody helpme ?

thanks

Comment: Show us your code!

Answer (score 1):

You should do it within one spider, in two functions:

```
...
def parse_categories(self, response):
    # some code here...
    for article in articles:
         yield scrapy.Request(url=article, callback=self.parse_article)
...
def parse_article(self, response):
    ....
    yield article_item
```